# How to find network Id of specific SSID?

Tags: android, wifimanager

since i am writing api where user will be passing SSID and password as parameters.I am trying to get network Id from SSID to forget that particular wifi.

Comment: Not expert but SSID isn't the id you are looking for ?

Comment: that is not possible because network IDs are unique and SSIDs are not

Comment: Without code people cannot help.  Do you have code to share?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure if your device is saving specific WiFi network, it's SSID and password saved only. For an instance, if You establish WiFi hot-spot with same SSID and password as your home network, your phone will connect to it automatically. That's why it's not safe to have open networks saved. You never know who is on the other side.

Didn't try this, but it seems all you need to do is something like this:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();

for(WifiConfiguration config : list){
    if("your_ssid".equals(config.SSID)){
        wifiMgr.removeNetwork(config.networkId)
    }
}
```

If you are targeting API >= 29 You should use

```
 wifiMgr.removeNetworkSuggestions (List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> networkSuggestions)
```

You can build suggestions like that:

```
final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion1 = new Builder()
  .setSsid("test111111")
  .build()
final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion2 = new Builder()
  .setSsid("test222222")
  .setWpa2Passphrase("test123456")
  .build()
final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion3 = new Builder()
  .setSsid("test333333")
  .setWpa3Passphrase("test6789")
  .build()
```

more info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder.html#build()